# Multiple post categories - single permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, seo

I created a post which is assigned to multiple categories.

Eg: I have a post "My Post", and I put it in "*foo*" and "*bar*" categories.
Now my article will have two permalinks, "*/foo/my-post*" and "*/bar/my-post*".
Google calls this a duplicate, which it considers to be spam, hence this is not what I want.

How can I use multiple categories but have the same permalink?
I want this only for SEO.

My current permalink structure is `/%category%/%post_id%-%postname%.html`

Comment: how are you outputting two different permalinks for the same post? this is not default behavior. WordPress generates a single permalink using the category with the lowest ID.

Comment: Your article will have just one permalink.

Comment: but why my article is visible at "/foo/my-post" and "/bar/my-post" ?

Comment: Google say that if will find same content at two different urls on the same site, it will consider it as duplicate => spam...

Comment: If your theme uses the API to output permalinks, only one permalink will ever be visible within your site for a given post, so how would Google find a URL which doesn't exist anywhere?

Comment: okay, but categories foo and bar are visible and shows list of aticles... so category foo links to permalink with foo/ and category bar links to permalink with bar/

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you use `%category%` in custom format field on Permalinks settings?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using category name in permalink for a post, it's not a good practice, especially, if you have two or more categories per post.

Solutions:
Use canonical link tag for the post and add it to your prefered absolute URL. Google will rank only this one and it won't be as duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

It can't generate 2 URLs for a single post. If not specified otherwise will probably take the variable /category/ from your first category. Not duplicate content.

This is a common Wordpress behavior. I'm seeing this on most of the websites I've published with that URL structure - `/%category%/%post_id%-%postname%.html`

I have also read your comment, and if your post shows with different URLs, although unlikely, there's something wrong with your setup.